# "linux" grub loader can't detect android

Tags: linux, windows, grub, android, bootloader

[volume][1]

I had installed Android(Bliss OS) in `New Volume(D)`. When I successfully installed it, I noticed that it was asking me to `use` or `reboot`. I was using few moment. When I reboot after using the Android. I noticed that grub loader isn't detecting Android(Bliss OS).

[bliss os is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q88Q9.png)
[screenshot of Bliss OS from Linux][2]

I have bliss OS in sda2. But, Linux grub loader is unable to detect it.

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="10C4F74DC4F73416" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Android-x86" UUID="7efe11c7-647a-471a-b149-fabbfa3e9c8c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="0A122C29122C1BE7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5144d217-9d4a-4e8c-b8d5-31959274dd51" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="b6f4d65c-46a0-4985-9ec3-dd0044257fcb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-06"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDXAy.jpg)

I had run above picture command. I got following error....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UizfO.jpg)

I was doing some changes by help of [the webpage](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/how-to-dual-boot-android-x86-and-ubuntu.html).

When I added following code at the bottom of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /android-4.0-RC1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=eeepc acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-4.0-RC1 SDCARD=/data/sdcard.img
initrd /android-4.0-RC1/initrd.img}
```

And, tried following command

```
root@istiak ~ # sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom  #permission 
root@istiak ~ # sudo update-grub           #updating grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

`/dev/sda2       209616896 272531455  62914560    30G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

I think I am having problem with `root='(hd0,2)'`. I didn't find `SDCARD=/data/sdcard.img`. There's only three `img` formatted file.Here are they.

[enter image description here][3]
I tried with system.img although I was getting same error.

I am unable to detect Android. What to do now? I think the question should be migrated to Unix SE(I am not sure). While Unix SE is completely for Linux.

After doing above changes I got android while I can't access it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NDxx.png)
Error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRlRm.png)

Comment: I don't think that an Android OS will boot from an NTFS formatted disk. Have you red the documentation? https://wiki.blissroms.org/index.php?title=Bliss_OS/Installation/Misc

Comment: @Robert Oh! Thanks `ext4` may work...!

Comment: @Robert I think something else is happening with it. It is now ext4 although it isn't showing. I was reading [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517212/booting-android-with-grub-but-how?newreg=47de920309d54e62a8fca5639029a35e) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/when-wouldnt-you-want-to-install-grub-bootloader) they were working with grub loader... Let me read the Bliss OS installation documentation also..!